# Editing old html pages to meat the new https standard

Tags: html, http, https

So our web host applied a free SSL cert, and without any changes our site now loads up https, however I started to notice some load issues with some links a while back - I found that adding https to the links made the strangeness some experienced go away. The site is very old html. So I was chasing link failures, not good.

Now our most visited pages have all https, or some https and http linkage.  Our archive pages are all http links, we have thousands of pages.

Should I just update all my links to https - links to images, to pages, all links. Is this now the best practice going forward? I imagine it is, but it would help me to have confirmation :)

I have searched this question of mine, but I think it's just to newbie-simple, and so I don't find a straight answer.

Comment: Yes it is, you update all your links to https.

Comment: Thanks for answering, sort of . . . if it's so obvious then why don't hosts inform customers to do this after install of cert?  Why when I researched SSL free certs did I not read it?

Comment: This leads me to think there are pros and cons - and so I come here, with my simple question, to learn more about it.